# How to avoid freezing the browser when adding a big HTML-Chunk (which was loaded via AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, dom

I have a web-app which displays information about various items. Only a small part of the items are being displayed initially. (the top level ones). When the page is initially loaded (and the first items are being displayed), I am requesting the full item list from the server via AJAX.

As soon as the request returns, i insert the items in a hidden div, so the user can search for any items. (If he initiates the search before the full list has loaded, he gets an appropriate "loading... spinner" in a modal dialog)

Now the only problem i have, is that after inserting the data fetched by ajax, (~10.000 items, ~40MB of generated HTML) the browser freezes for up to 40 seconds.

My code is:

```
$.ajax({url: uri, data: { .... }})
        .done(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                data = $.trim(data); // takes about 35 ms
                setupFullTree(data);
        })

function setupFullTree (data,s){
    $tree.append('<div id="i-full-tree" data-status="loading" style="display:none"></div>'); // takes no measurable time
    $('#i-full-tree').append(data); // takes between 10000 and 40000 ms, depending on the browser, ...
    indexFts(); // takes about 50ms
}
```

Which "pattern" can I use to make my web-app responsible during this? Do I have to split it into small chunks (it is a tree like structure, so this isn't easy). And do i need to use setTimeout then while inserting? Is there a way to move some of the necessary computations in a WebWorker?

Comment: the... "freezing" is likely due to the amount of information you're trying to append. Have you considered appending less?

Comment: Ideally, you want to have less stuff in the DOM at once. Think of something like a paging system: you only show what's absolutely critical and load in more data as needed.

Comment: Loading a page with that amount of data without Ajax would also take forever. Paging, progressive loading, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the ajax response data, which you want to display in a tree structure, in a js variable, and then load say first 100 items and then load if the user scrolls to the end of the data.

Comment: The user usually wont scroll through the 10000 elements. He will usually search for the item by entering some information. If I already have  inserted the data in the DOM, i simply make the matching parts visible. I guess I could search through the js-data, and only append the matches.

Comment: Right. You search the js object/array and then append only those. To make it much more efficient, you can make a requirement for the user to enter minimum 2-3 characters to avoid too many matches. Another way will be to search the beginning of the strings in your object instead of matching any part of the strings.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.